how to write values ​to arc<rwlock<hashmap<>>> out of the loop
I have a loop in which a program receives a message via a web socket and writes information about the user (from the message) to the 'database?'.
#[derive(Debug)]
struct ChatUser{
    name: String,
    password: String,
}

static NEW_USER_ID: AtomicUsize = AtomicUsize::new(1);
type UserDB = Arc<RwLock<HashMap<usize, ChatUser>>>;

async fn web_socket(mut ws: WebSocket, State(state): State<UserDB>) {
    let new_id = NEW_USER_ID.fetch_add(1, std::sync::atomic::Ordering::Relaxed);
    while let Ok(Message::Text(message)) = ws.next().await.unwrap(){
        let user_info: Value = serde_json::from_str(&message.trim()).unwrap();
            let (name, password) = (user_info["name"].to_string(),    user_info["password"].to_string());
            state.write().await.insert(new_id, ChatUser { name: name, password: password }).expect("cant write"); 
            println!("{:?}",state);
    }
}

state.write does not work correctly when run in a loop... outside the loop everything works correctly
Is it possible to take values ​​out of the loop? or write them down in the state in some other way?
if I run the code and send message to socket
thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' panicked at src/main.rs:41:93:
cant write
stack backtrace:
   0: rust_begin_unwind
             at /rustc/3f5fd8dd41153bc5fdca9427e9e05be2c767ba23/library/std/src/panicking.rs:652:5
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/3f5fd8dd41153bc5fdca9427e9e05be2c767ba23/library/core/src/panicking.rs:72:14
   2: core::panicking::panic_display
             at /rustc/3f5fd8dd41153bc5fdca9427e9e05be2c767ba23/library/core/src/panicking.rs:262:5
   3: core::option::expect_failed
             at /rustc/3f5fd8dd41153bc5fdca9427e9e05be2c767ba23/library/core/src/option.rs:1995:5
   4: core::option::Option<T>::expect [............]

how can I fix it?
"can't write" <--- is the message form state.write.await.insert.expect("can't write")

HashMap::insert will return the previous value if it existed, so your .expect() will panic if the value didn't already exist, which I'm guessing is not what you wanted (it is new_id after all). Just remove the .expect().

https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html

insert writes the new value inside, doesn't it?

Yes, but the returned value is Option<V>, Some(V) of the old value when the key already in the HashMap, and None when it is a entirely new key. I.e. when first insert a key, it will return None, you should just let _ = it .

The message in the expect shows the nature of the confusion. If state.write() returned a Result, an expect("can't write") would make sense and be necessary, but it would be in a different place: state.write().await.expect("can't write").insert(...). But it doesn't, and your expect() is placed to apply to the Option returned by HashMap::insert(). A message that reflected what it does would be something along the lines of expect("didn't overwrite previous value"). Since you don't want to assert that you've overwritten a previous value, the expect() can be removed.

I gave this message to understand which line of code causes the error, I did not give any special meaning to the message

There are 2 problem
HashMap Insert
The returned value of HashMap::insert() is Option<V>, which does not represent if the insertion is successful, it is always successful, however,

Some(V) of the old value when the key already in the HashMap, and
None when it is a entirely new key. I.e. when first insert a key, it will return None, you should just let _ = it .

use std::collections::HashMap;
fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    // the first time inserting a key return `None`
    assert_eq!(None, map.insert("My Key", 69));
    // subsequent insertion return the already inserted value
    assert_eq!(Some(69), map.insert("My Key", 420));
}

Break Value out of loop
It's the wrong question but here is an answer anyway,
You can change the while loop to a loop loop, and break a loop with a value.
let error: std::io::Error = loop {
    // do whatever task 
    // blah blah blah
    //...
    
    // some how encounter a Result type
    let result: Result<i32, std::io::Error> = /* some error-able things */;


    let ok_i32 = match result {
        // safely unwrap the result into Ok(_)
        Ok(i) => i,
        // return the error
        Err(e) => break e,
    };
    
    // Keep doing whatever task
    drop(ok_i32);
};


let _ = ... is unnecessary and unidiomatic for HashMap::insert(). Option is not Result and it's perfectly fine to just discard it. In other words, instead of let _ = map.insert(...) as suggested by the answer, it's fine to just use map.insert(...).
